How to add properties for QObject on-the-fly?
I have a class that inherits from QObject. It contains a big dictionary of strings.
I want to use all of them as properties to be able use them in assignments and QML.
Now my class looks like this:
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Property
from functools import partial

class Strings(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Strings, self).__init__(parent)
        self._strings = {
            'MainWindowTitle': 'Window',
            'DriverNotLoadedStatus': 'Driver not loaded',
            'DriverLoadedStatus': 'Driver loaded',
        }
        self._build_attrs()
        # super(Strings, self).__init__(parent)

    def _build_attrs(self):
        def common_getter(obj: Strings, prop: str):
            return obj._strings[prop]
        
        def common_setter(obj: Strings, value, prop: str):
            if getattr(obj, prop) != value:
                obj._strings[prop] = value
                signal_name = f'{prop}_changed'
                signal = getattr(obj, signal_name)
                signal.emit()

        for key in self._strings.keys():
            signal_name = f'{key}_changed'
            notifySignal = Signal()
            setattr(Strings, signal_name, notifySignal)
            getter = partial(common_getter, prop=key)
            setter = partial(common_setter, prop=key)
            setattr(Strings, key, Property(str, getter, setter, notify=notifySignal))


But it doesn't work. Assignments and notifications works, but I can't access these properties in QML.
I think this is because these properties wasn't added into QMetaObject, but I don't know how to do it on-the-fly.
I tried to call constructor of base class after the all properties were added (look commented line in the code), but it doesn't help.
Only signals are available in QML, but not properties.
How to fix it?

Simple: you can't; not like this. Properties, as much as slots and signals, can only be defined at the class level, cannot be added on an already existing instance; the fact that signals worked may just be a coincidence. The problem is that all those aspects should be added before the instance is created, so the only way is through metaclasses, or with a function that dynamically creates classes. See this related post: How to create PyQt Properties dynamically.

I want you to have an XY problem, your goal is to expose a dictionary to QML, not to create attributes of a QObject.

@eyllanesc, if I'd exposed a dictionary to QML, I wouldn't be able to get notification of each dictionary's element separately.

@musicamante, thanks, I successed using metaclass.

@maestro If the link above solved your issue, then please notify us, as we could mark this question as duplicate. If, still, your implementation was only conceptually based on that and took many different steps to achieve your goals, then please consider using the "Answer your question" button and provide an appropriate solution (including a relevant, comprehensive [mre]). Note that if those "properties" are never accessed individually when setting them (eg: you just update the dictionary), then there's no point in all that: just write a proper setter that checks the differences.
